How to scheduled a cron job in Next.js (not deploy and run in Vercel)?
How can I scheduled a cron job using cron together with Next.js 14 application? For example, I want to run a job every specific interval to update the database tables and etc.
It looks like many developers are configuring the cron jobs in vercel.json and run them in Vercel. Can we do the similar thing if not deploying our Next.js in Vercel like running in AWS EC2 or other server?

Vercel's Cron Job feature makes an HTTP GET request to the deployed project's production deployment URL at the specified endpoint. The schedule field uses the same syntax as the crontab.
If you are deploying the code on AWS EC2, you can add the cronjob directly. And instead of specifying the endpoint directly, you can use curl in crontab.
The guide on how to set up a corn job using crontab: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job
Example
If you setup a cron job w/ Vercel Cron Job feature:
{
  "crons": [
    {
      "path": "/api/cron",
      "schedule": "0 5 * * *"
    }
  ]
}

The identical crontab would be:
0 5 * * * curl -s -o /dev/null https://your-project-id.vercel.app/api/cron


So I need to create an unprotected route to perform internal clean-up and trigger it using cron job. Do you know if we can limit the call to this API route within the server and not from the public Internet?
